# How to use combined filters in opencart 2.0.1.1?

Tags: php, filter, opencart, opencart2.x, opencart-module

I've ran into a problem with the standard filter in Opencart 2.0.1.1. I want to filter products with multiple filters so the products will be narrowed down.

I found a solution, but that one was for [Opencart 1.5](http://forum.opencart.com/viewtopic.php?f=19&t=93595&sid=f21e8207e3fc395c24c07d8fa2cd47fc&start=20#p401453)

I know there are several filter extension that do this, but why should I buy another extension? This needs to be a default functionality imo.

I have knowlegde of PHP so I can edit the models/templates myself, I just need to now what to edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For people who are looking at the same problem, I fanally found this amazing extention that adds the missing "AND" in the sql query.

http://www.opencart.com/index.php?route=extension/extension/info&extension_id=23603

> The default filters in Opencart uses logic "OR" for all values,
>   regardless of the filter group.
>
> FixFilter OC2x modifies the default Opencart 2.0 filters to filter
>   products with "OR" (products in group) and "AND" (for GROUPS) logic.
>
> Designed for Opencart version 2.0.0.0 - 2.0.3.1 This fix is not
>   necessary if you use a third-party filter (such as FilterPro etc)
>
> Install Upload file fix_filter.ocmod.xml in Extension Installer Don`t
>   forget refresh modification cache after install!

Comment: It still is not working for me... any ideas mine is 2.2 version of opencart

Comment: Got the right version installed? Try to reinstall it and clear your cache.

Comment: the version i have downloaded is FixFilterOC2x1.00en, I have tried twice buddy,